# Why does my computer restart every time I try to play CS:GO?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

My Counter Strike: Global Offense game automatically restarts my computer before it finishes loading up, I don't see a loading screen or a menu screen. I've never played it before and all I've done is put it as a desktop Icon, I did some similar research on someone who had the same problem (but with Skyrim) and have yet to find any solution.

Comment: prevent the computer from restarting [details of how to do this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091229145934AAjQ7oj) and see what the actual error message is. it's likely something to do with your video card, though.

Comment: Can you try to re-validate your CS:GO game content? You can right-click on the game in your steam library and click validation.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely experiencing a [STOP error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death) which causes your system to stop responding and your computer is not able to recover from it. STOP errors are more commonly known as Blue Screens of Death or BSODs. However your computer restarts immediately rather than show you the actual error message (see TZHX's comment how to fix that). STOP errors are generally caused by hardware, drivers or system updates. It's difficult to diagnose exactly what is wrong from the information provided, so I would recommend that you ensure your system is up to date by downloading the latest operating system updates, drivers and verify game cache. Outside of the game, malicious software such as trojans and root-kits can cause this behaviour so scan your computer to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will help you to stop the restarting:

1. Click on the Start button and then on Control Panel.
2. Click on the System and Security link.
3. Click on the System link.
4. In the task pane on the left, click the Advanced system settings link.
5. Locate the Startup and Recovery section near the bottom of the window and click on the Settings button.
6. In the Startup and Recovery window, locate and remove the check box next to Automatically restart.
7. Click OK in the Startup and Recovery window.
8. Click OK in the System Properties window.
9. You can now close the System window.
10. From now on, when a problem causes a BSOD or another major error that halts the system, Windows 7 will not force a reboot. You'll have to reboot manually when an error appears.

Are you using a laptop or a PC? 
Knowing what operating system, graphics card and other relevant settings might be helpful, too.